# Distinct records based on some columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `myTable` in SQL server database. Let`s say the name of columns is like:

> col1, col2, col3, col4, col5

There are thousands of records in the table. 
I want to select records with no repetition based on only 4 columns.

currently I use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable
```

The query does return unique and distinct records, however I need to have col5 in the result too, even thought I do not want to `col5` to be considered when I distinct records.
for example, there are three records in the table as follows:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5    
 1      2      3      4      5       
 2      5      6      9      7     
 1      2      3      4      10
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5         
  1      2      3      4      5       
  1      2      3      4      10
```

Comment: I thought you wanted distinct rows of col1..4 - here, you have two rows with the same values to these columns. Are you sure you've removed the correct row?

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, min(col5) as col5
    FROM myTable
    group by col1, col2, col3, col4`

Comment: @Mureinik I do want distinct rows of col1..4 and I do not have any problem with it, however I want col5 to be in the result too. it means that we have some records that are mutual only in some columns and not only we want to find these records, but also we want all the columns in the result too.

Comment: Then tell us the rule which of those col5 values you want to have. Just any value? If you want something specific - be specific.

Comment: @juergend in my case in here, only the type `Integer` for col5. that`s it

Comment: I mean your example data - it does not fit your description.

Comment: I thought it may be clear. I want exactly the same result that I wrote in the question. I mean with the records(in the question) in the table, I want two records with all 5 columns in the result. is it clear? you guys give minus to those questions that you do not fully understand?!

Comment: Do you have an id column that uniquly identifies a record? Is it `col1`?

Comment: @juergend yes, exactly! col5 is the identity column in the table. col1..4 are of type 'varchar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will give you the records you like but only `col1` to `col4`:

```
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
  FROM myTable     
  group by col1, col2, col3, col4
  having count(*) > 1
```

If you also need `col5` then use

```
select t1.* 
from myTable t1
join
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
  FROM myTable     
  group by col1, col2, col3, col4
  having count(*) > 1
) t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
    and t1.col2 = t2.col2
    and t1.col3 = t2.col3
    and t1.col4 = t2.col4
```

### Edit

After you edited your question, this is the answer:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, min(col5) as col5     
FROM myTable     
group by col1, col2, col3, col4
```